# Let $f(x) \in \Bbb Z_p[x]$. Prove that if $f(x)$ has no factor of the form $x^2 + ax + b$, then it has no quadratic factor over $\Bbb Z_p$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, proof-verification

Let $f(x) \in \Bbb Z_p[x]$.  Prove that if $f(x)$ has no factor of the form $x^2 + ax + b$, then it has no quadratic factor over $\Bbb Z_p$.

So if $f(x) \neq (x^2 + ax + b)h(x)$, then if $h(x) = cg(x)$ for some $c \in \Bbb Z_p$.

Therefore $f(x) \neq (cx^2 + cax + bc)g(x) \neq (cx^2 + dx + e)g(x)$.

I don't feel this is right, but I can't figure any other way to show this, anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You've got the basic idea for the proof itself, but you are going about it the wrong way. As it's stated, it doesn't prove anything about an *arbitrary* $g$, which is what you need. Recall that any if-then statement is equivalent to its contra-positive. I.e., prove that if $f$ has any quadratic factor, then it has one of form $x^2 + ax + b$. This is equivalent.